# Memory allocation in stack and deletion of local variables

Tags: java, stack, heap-memory

I am new to java programming and trying to understand how memory is allocated in stack. I read that at compile time, methods containing local variable are stored. Once, methods are used then these local variables are deleted from stack. My question is, what does happen when I call same method again. If memory was allocated at compile time and once method is executed and deleted from stack, then what will happen if I call method again? Thanks.

Memory allocation. Stack. Heap.

void somefunction(`enter code here`) {
    Member m;
}

Comment: where did you read that "at compile time, methods containing local variable are stored"? At compile time the required size on the stack, and relative location of each variable is determined, but memory is only stored (consumed) at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

A stack is allocated for every thread. When you enter a method, a new layer (called officially a frame) is added to the stacktrace with corresponding variables. Once the method is finished, that "layer" is remove from the stacktrace.

If you enter that method again, it will simply add it again, from a fresh start and so on. If you call it recursively, you will have multiple layers with same method.